# Storing ouput of shuf into a variable

Tags: bash, terminal

I have the following code which gives me a random word from a file I have.

```
shuf -n 1 /home/mirwais/etc/dictionary.txt
```

The problem is that I want the output to be stored into a variable. It now just prints the random word into the console.

I have tried :

```
word= shuf -n 1 /home/mirwais/etc/dictionary.txt
```

and

```
word=""
shuf -n 1 /home/mirwais/etc/dictionary.txt | $word
```

without succes

Comment: Looking at just about *any* shell question on this site would have found you the syntax that you needed for this as it appears **everywhere**. As would having looked at just about any shell programming introduction,m just about any shell manual, etc. You are expected to do some minimum amount of investigation into your question before asking it on this site.

Comment: If you're going to be writing Bash scripts then consider reading the [Bash Reference Manual (PDF)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf) or [Bash Reference Manual (HTML)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

word=$(shuf -n 1 /home/mirwais/etc/dictionary.txt)